# git check if working copy repository exists and validate it

Tags: git, validation, repository, local, working-copy

1. I'm looking for a way to test **local** directory against presence of a git repository.
   I would not like just to check by sh/bash if the `.git` sub directory exist but rather use dedicated git command if there is a one.
2. I want to validate potentially found git repository in that **local** directory by a git command.

Do you know any git commands to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For item 1, use `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`.  This:

- prints `false` if you are in a Git repository but not within its work-tree (i.e., are in a bare repository);
- prints `true` if you are in a Git repository that has a work-tree; or
- errors (prints `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to...` to stderr) if you are not in a Git repository.

Note, however, that if you are in a Git repository whose work-tree is damaged or modified in some way, Git will print `true` here.  If you pass `--git-dir=` and a path to a valid repository, Git *always* thinks you are in a work-tree (because you are).  The exit status of this command is zero if it printed either `true` or `false`, and nonzero if it produced an error.

For item 2—"validating" the repository—this depends entirely on what you mean by "validate".

Comment: I consider at this stage a valid local repository if I can commit to it, checkout its branches, generate log etc. No need for interchanging data with a remote repository.

Comment: To commit or check out, you need a work-tree, so check `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository`, which prints `true` or `false` or errors. This is functionally the same as `--is-inside-work-tree`, but states your intent more clearly. Note that you can run `git log` on a bare repository.

Comment: I could not get a proper output by using `--git-dir="<path-to-repository>"` but with the option `-C <path>` it worked and detected bare/non-bare repositories and also it gave an error if there was no repository. Full command: `git -C <path-to-repository> rev-parse --is-bare-repository`

Comment: @Jimmix: the `--git-dir` setting would be the path plus `/.git` for a non-bare repository. Using `-C` is probably better here.